# Python keyword arguments unpack and return dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, argument-unpacking

I have a function definition as below and I am passing keyword arguments. How do I get to return a dictionary with the same name as the keyword arguments?

Manually I can do:

```
def generate_student_dict(first_name=None, last_name=None , birthday=None, gender =None):
    return {
        'first_name': first_name,
        'last_name': last_name,
        'birthday': birthday,
        'gender': gender
    }
```

But I don't want to do that. Is there any way that I can make this work without actually typing the dict?

```
 def generate_student_dict(self, first_name=None, last_name=None, birthday=None, gender=None):
     return # Packed value from keyword argument.
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Initially I wanted to pass this return dict to Django's Model create method. @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If that way is suitable for you, use [kwargs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (see [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)) as in code snippet below:

```
def generate_student_dict(self, **kwargs):            
     return kwargs
```

Otherwise, you can create a copy of params with [`built-in locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) at function start and **return** that copy:

```
def generate_student_dict(first_name=None, last_name=None , birthday=None, gender =None):
     # It's important to copy locals in first line of code (see @MuhammadTahir comment).
     args_passed = locals().copy()
     # some code
     return args_passed

generate_student_dict()
```

Comment: locals() will only work if there is no variable defined in the body of the method :)

Comment: @MuhammadTahir Thanks for your correction, i've updated answer

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to pass `**kwargs`, you can simply return [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#locals):

```
def generate_student_dict(first_name=None, last_name=None, 
                          birthday=None, gender=None):
    return locals()
```

Note that you want to remove `self` from the result if you pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Get keyword arguments in `**kwargs`

```
def generate_student_dict(self, **kwargs):
  # use it like
  # kwargs.get('first_name')
  # kwargs.get('last_name')
  # kwargs.get('birthday')
  # kwargs.get('gender')
  return kwargs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()` function. `locals()` updates and returns a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by `locals()` when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks.

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to return the updated values as dictionary

```
    def generate_student_dict(first_name=None, last_name=None , birthday=None, gender =None):
        main_args = locals().copy()
        first_name = 'first'
        last_name = 'last'
        birthday = '20 jan 1993'
        newvar = 100
        new_args = locals().copy()
        updated_args = {}

        for k,v in new_args.items():
            if k in main_args.keys():
                updated_args[k] = v
        return updated_args

    dict = generate_student_dict()
    print(dict) #{'first_name': 'first', 'last_name': 'last', 'birthday': '20 jan 1993', 'gender': None}
```

In case you want to return the iniital values as dictionary

```
    def generate_student_dict_1(first_name=None, last_name=None , birthday=None, gender =None):
        args = locals()
        first_name = 'first'
        last_name = 'last'
        birthday = '20 jan 1993'
        newvar = 100
        return args

    dict = generate_student_dict_1()
    print(dict) #{'first_name': None, 'last_name': None, 'birthday': None, 'gender': None}
```

if you want to include all the changes including extra variables defined inside the method

```
    def generate_student_dict_2(first_name=None, last_name=None , birthday=None, gender =None):
        first_name = 'first'
        last_name = 'last'
        birthday = '20 jan 1993'
        newvar = 100
        args = locals()
        return args

    dict = generate_student_dict_2()
    print(dict) #{'first_name': 'first', 'last_name': 'last', 'birthday': '20 jan 1993', 'gender': None, 'newvar': 100}
```